# Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre dette et créance?

Tags: définition

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre dette et créance ?

Dans ce [lien](https://www.telos-eu.com/fr/le-parlement-italien-envisage-une-monnaie-parallel.html), l'auteur du texte écrit «(...) comme la réduction des obstacles à la consolidation entre créances et dettes, (...)»

Answer (score 9, accepted):

L'un est l'inverse de l'autre, simplement...

Une dette est une somme due par un débiteur à un créancier

Une créance désigne le droit pour le créancier d'exiger du débiteur la remise de cette somme.

Source : [Droit-finances](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/faq/20375-dette-et-creance-definition-et-differences)

Comment: Merci. +1 pour le lien ;)